# How to make Typescript wait for a function to execute

Tags: typescript

I have two functions like this

```
const ResultTest=new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
                         GetUserDataField(userField);
                });
```

And another function below like show..it seems this GetUserDataField is never executed or executed only after ResultTest is completed

```
 function GetUserDataField(userField: string): Promise<boolean> {
      return false;
    }
```

I want to delay the code execution till GetUserDataField is executed

Note : I am new to typescript and promises

Comment: You are not resolving the promise? Neither is `GetUserDataField` returning a promise.

Comment: You want me to add a promise to GetUserDataField too?

Comment: Does this compile? `GetUserDataField` is typed to return a `Promise`, but it just returns false.

Comment: Yes it complies but I am doing something basically wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the promise, and I doubt GetUserDataField compiles ( at least on any later version of typescript )

You need at least

```js
function GetUserDataField(userField: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return Promise.resolve(false);
}
```